# Asset not appearing

Tags: templating, assets

I am pulling assets from the work section like this-

```
<div class="header_image">
  {% for entry in craft.entries.section('work').limit(5) %}
            <a href="{{ entry.url }}">  
            <div class="mainImage" style="background-image:url({{ asset.url }})"> </div>
            </a> 
  {% endfor %}
```

The Asset isn't appearing on the page but if I hover over where the image should, the link is working properly and I can to get that entry. The asset.url isn't working and I'm not sure what else it should be. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you know the asset exists first:

```
{% if entry.asset.first() %}
  <div class="mainImage" style="background-image:url({{ entry.asset.first().url }})"></div>
{% endif %}
```

Another nifty trick is to enable "dev mode". This will give you detailed stack traces about what's going wrong in your instance!

http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/config-settings#devMode

Comment: that didn't work. but dev mode is telling me it's this line- <div class="mainImage" style="background-image:url({{ asset.url }})"> </div>

Comment: Is `asset` the fieldname you've used? It should be attached to the `entry` object as well. So it should look like ```{{ entry.yourCustomFieldname.first().url }}```.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you are calling `asset.url` rather than `entry.asset.first.url`. The variable 'asset' does not exist. The asset is a field of the entry, and must be referenced as such.

Edit: I assumed your field name was called 'asset'. You should be calling entry.assetFieldHandle.first.url.

Comment: Are you saying that I should have this - <div class="mainImage" style="background-image:url({{ entry.asset.first.url }})"> </div> because that doesn't work. I had this working perfectly before, I can't figure out what has gone wrong.

Comment: So, the variable asset doesn't exist. But if I replace asset.url with entry.asset.first.url, I get 'do not have a method or closure named "asset"

Comment: what is the name of your asset field? You'll access the asset via entry.<assetFieldName>

Comment: So it should be this?   <div class="header_image">
      {% for entry in craft.entries.section('work').limit(5) %}
                <a href="{{ entry.url }}">  
                <div class="mainImage" style="background-image:url({{ entry.asset('mainImages').url }} )"> </div>
                </a>      
      {% endfor %}
    </div>

Comment: Try entry.mainImages.first.url